# Trouble configuring firewall for FTP on Windows Server 2008 R2

Tags: iis-7, windows-server-2008-r2, ftp, windows-firewall

Ok, I'm having the exact same problem as in this question [outbound ftp on server 2008 r2 stalls](https://serverfault.com/questions/59635/outbound-ftp-on-server-2008-r2-stalls) but the accepted answer didn't help me much...

I followed the third step of this http://learn.iis.net/page.aspx/309/configuring-ftp-firewall-settings/ guide in order to configure my firewall for FTP, and I am able to authenticate, however, the data channel doesn't seem to be passing through the firewall. If I disable the firewall, everything works fine. Hope someone can help me, as this is really starting to annoy me.

Best regards,
x3ro

Comment: did you try following the article http://blogs.msdn.com/vivekkum/archive/2008/09/10/out-of-band-ftp-7-shows-operation-timed-out.aspx

Answer (score 4):

You need to allow the ftp server through the firewall.  The default entry in the firewall is incorrect.  Assuming you already have the correct ports open, you also need to do the following:

1. Search for 'firewall' in the start menu search
2. Click on 'Allow a program through Windows Firewall'
3. There is a default entry for 'FTP Server', however this is NOT the one you need.  In fact, if you have a look at the windows service for the FTP server, it is invoked via svchost.exe.  Click on the 'Allow another program...' button, and enter C:\Windows\System32\svchost.exe.
4. Once you have added this entry, tick the checkbox for both Home/Work and Public profiles.

This will allow you to successfully use the FTP server with the firewall turned on.